# Printing the reverse of a linked list

Tags: c++

I'm working on a problem where I am trying to print out a number line. I have an object that contains two linked lists. One list is positive numbers (including zero) and one linked list that is negative numbers (starting at -1) and I have pointers to the head of each list. What I am trying to do is print out the list in order. So if the negative linked list has five nodes and the positive list has six nodes I want to print out

```
-5 -4 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

I have written code to print out the positive list in order. I having a hard time figuring out how to print the negative list in reverse order. The function is overridding the << operator and looks like the following:

```
// output operator
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, numberLine const& obj) {
    LinkedListNode* temp = obj.negHeader;
    int counter = 0;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp = temp->next;
        counter++;
    }
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        for (counter; counter > 0; counter--) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        os << temp->value;
    }


    //everything under this prints the nonNeg list

    temp = obj.nonNegHeader;
    //goes through the nonNeg list and prints each element if its not null
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        os << temp->value;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return os;

}
```

The code on the bottom is printing the positive linked list which is pretty basic. The top part is my attempt to try and print the negative list in reverse order but it doesn't work and I'm not sure that is even the direction I should go in doing this.

Comment: You will have a hard time iterating backwards through a singly linked list.  That is the essence of your problem.

Comment: There's a trick you can use, if you're willing to recurse

Answer (score 3):

You could make a recursive function like:

```
void print_list_reverse(LinkedListNode* current_node) {
    if (current_node->next != NULL) print_list_reverse(current_node->next);
    os << current_node->value;
}
```

This will keep going in until it reaches the end of the list, and print every value on its way back.

Just keep in mind that if your list is too big, it might break.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: it *will* also break (no might about it), if you pass a null list pointer. It won't take much to fix that problem, btw.